# Using Case WHEN to extract with first character

Tags: sql, hive

I am using case as an if else statement in my hive database, it seems it is not showing what i am trying to extract as.

i am using this script

```
case when substr(file_name, length(file_name) - 44 , 1) like '%_' then substr(file_name, length(file_name) - 44 , 9) else substr(file_name, length(file_name) - 45 , 9) END
```

in logical concept
if at character 44 starts with _ , substring at 45 , else substring at 45

e.g (table look like )

```
it is extracting the data from column file name which is 
row_1| abcdefghijklmn_20171120_
row_1| abcdefghijklmn_20181130_
row_1| abcdefghijklmno_20171120_

this is what it returns 
20171120
20181130
_20190721

it should return as this without _ character
20171120
20181130
20190721
```

am i using like statement correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to replace the value:

```
replace(case when substr(file_name, length(file_name) - 44 , 1) like '%_'
           then substr(file_name, length(file_name) - 44 , 9)
           else substr(file_name, length(file_name) - 45 , 9) END
        end, '_', '')
```

However, I think `regexp_extract()` might be simpler:

```
regexp_extract(file_name, '^.{44}_?([0-9]{8})', '1')
```

The pattern may be simpler, if there is only one sequence of 8 digits surrounded by underscores:

```
regexp_extract(file_name, '_([0-9]{8})_', '1')
```

Comment: Nice. i didnt thought of using regular expression. this did solve my problem . However, i am thinking if i were to use replace method that you provided. would that be a good practice?

Comment: @user12883347 . . . The regular expression is so much simpler that I would suggest going with that.

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL LIKE statement, the '%' character means "match anything or nothing", and '_' means any single character. Wrapping either of those characters in square brackets escapes them.

So, when you say some thing is `LIKE '%_'` that will be interpreted as "any character or none, and ends in a single character". This effectively is just checking to see if the string length is at least 1.

If you're trying to match the ones *prefixed* with a literal underscore, you'll want to escape the underscore, and change it to `LIKE '[_]%'`. (That means "starts with literally one underscore, followed by anything or nothing".)

Hope this helps! :)
[Edited per jarlh's comment on the _ wildcard. Thanks!]

Comment: The underscore is also a LIKE wildcard, which stands for exactly one character.

Comment: Thanks for the note @jarlh. I edited the answer with that in mind.